# Replace current process by its coprocess/child

Tags: shell, scripting, process, zsh

I have a program `P` that expects to receive "Hello" and output "Why?" before providing a feature.  This feature is used by other programs that are not aware that it is common courtesy to start a conversation with "Hello".  I thus want to write a wrapper for `P` that works like this (zsh syntax):

```
coproc P
print -p Hello  # Send Hello to P
read -pr line   # Read what P has to say
[[ "$line" = "Why?" ]] && Replace current process with the coprocess.
echo Could not get P's attention.
```

Using `cat` or `dd` in the `Replace...` part (something like `cat <&p &; exec cat >&p`) results in unnecessary buffering.  What are my options?

Comment: Do you want a `zsh` solution or is a `bash` solution acceptable?

Comment: I'd be disappointed by a `bash` solution that is not applicable in `zsh`, but would certainly accept it ☺

Comment: Is it known what other programs would be running this script? Is it a finite list, or could it be any number? Clearly the other program needs to know about this one in order to call it.

Comment: My typical use was with `ssh` and its option `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: I suspect this is a use case for `expect`.

Comment: I don't know about `expect`.  I've tried for a few minutes, but I cannot manage to mute the output of `P` when in noninteractive mode.

Comment: `cat` generally doesn't buffer. If it does on your system, try `cat -u`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've stated isn't really about replacing a *process*, but replacing an existing process's *streams*. The goal is to interact a bit with the process then hand over its input/output to another pair of connected streams.

There is no way to do this directly (at least, in the shell; inside the process, a `dup2` call might conceivably work). You will need to splice the streams. I.e:

```
( echo Hello ; cat ) | P | ( read ; cat )
```

Using `coproc` as in your example is OK too. Note that the command saves the file descriptors to an array, and you can later use them for redirections.

This should not cause additional buffering (at least with GNU cat), unless P inspects the input/output streams it's connected to and makes a decision to buffer based on that. For example, the C standard library will enable buffering on `stdout`/`stderr` if they are connected to a file, but only perform line buffering if they're connected to a terminal.

Comment: `coproc` doesn't save fds in arrays in `zsh`, you may be confusing with `bash`'s `coproc`. See [How do you use the command coproc in various shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270)

Answer (score -1):

Able to test with below code using perl to avoid buffering, try if this works for you

> Sample version of P

```
$ cat /tmp/P
#!/bin/bash
read input
if [[ $input = "Hello" ]]
then
    echo "Why?"
else
    exit 1
fi
echo "Got Hello from client, working ..."
sleep 10
echo "Need to read some input"
read x
echo "Got: $x"
```

> The wrapper program

```
$ cat /tmp/wrapper 
#!/usr/bin/zsh
coproc /tmp/P
print -p Hello  # Send Hello to P
read -pr line   # Read what P has to say
if [[ "$line" = "Why?" ]]; then
    perl -e '$|=1;print $_ while(<>);' <& p &
    perl -e '$|=1;print $_ while(<>);' >& p
else
    echo "Could not get P's attention."
fi
```

> Test run
>
> ```
> $ /tmp/wrapper 
> Got Hello from client, working ...
> Need to read some input
> hi there P!   <== Typed in at teminal
> Got: hi there P!
> ```

Comment: This is the same as using `dd ibs=1`, for instance.  I'm not fine with this.  In a way, the coproc has its own buffering, and it is this one that I want to use.